# Execute a shell command upon a click event in a web page

Tags: shell, browser, events

Is there a way to execute a bash command when I click on a text in a browser?

The web page is on computer A, the browser is on computer B : I want to execute the code on computer B, e.g `hsetroot` to change the wallpaper when clicking an image.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solve it using a nodeJS server. (not clean/final code but its working)

Computer A : (server)

```
function change_wallpaper(image){
    var objReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    objReq.open("GET", "http://localhost:8888" + "?image=" + image, false);
    objReq.send(null);
}
<img src="./img/1.jpeg" onclick="change_wallpaper(this.src);" />
<img src="./img/2.jpeg" onclick="change_wallpaper(this.src);" />
```

Computer B : (client)
file called `server.js` ans executed with `nodejs server.js`

```
var http = require("http");
var sys = require('sys')
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var url = require("url");

function onRequest(request, response) {
    var params = url.parse(request.url,true).query;
    function puts(error, stdout, stderr) {sys.puts(stdout)}
    exec("/usr/bin/feh --bg-center " + params.image, puts);
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    response.end('Wallpaper');
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
```

Comment: as my answer led you to the method to use, you asked for, it would have been nice to just ask for an edit for my answer, including your code and except it as I describe a method to execute a shell command, as you asked for and its a general approach. Writing portable services for client machines can do many, many things. If you would vote for my answer that would be ok too.

Comment: @ikrabbe the OP can't vote, they don't have the rep. As for accepting, yes your answer (which I did upvote) did indeed give them a pointer but you didn't explain _how_ they could use nodejs nor did you give an example. Your answer was very useful but it didn't really solve the OP's problem, it only pointed them in the right direction. Posting their own answer and accepting it is perfectly OK.

Answer (score 9):

Not really, no. That is the mother of all security holes. You are asking if you can set up a webpage that executes arbitrary commands on the client's machine. What if I set up a webpage that runs this command:

```
rm -rf ~/
```

That would delete all files in your `$HOME`. In fact, there was recently an uproar when [a bug was discovered](https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2014-6271) that allowed this to happen. [One of the possible attack vectors](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/68203) was tricking the client (computer B in your case) into running a bash command.

So no, you can't execute arbitrary code on your local machine through a web browser. Not without somehow logging in first. You can run JavaScript or similar language commands but they won't have access to your user's session.

Comment: Thank for the answer, i understand the obvious issue there. I'm trying to achieve that with a custom browser : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30963508/add-possibility-to-launch-commands-from-browser

Comment: @bobdylan I don't think that's possible. I certainly hope it isn't anyway. That's a cool little program, by the way. I had no idea it was that simple to do! The point, however, is that I don't think it is possible to initiate a local shell session from the browser.

Comment: Well let's say i want to make an hybrid website / program with some functionality linked to my OS. So my browser won't be a normal "browser". So i don't see how it's not possible.

Comment: Certainly it’s possible for a program to do.  Consider: there’s no difference, in principle, between an FTP client and a browser (an HTTP client) — both interact with a local user and with a server.  Trivially, the FTP client can modify local files and execute (some) local commands.  Sure, it’s only at the request of the user, but that’s not a real constraint.  So a browser *can* do the same.  I heard, about ten years ago, that some of the major browsers had a security setting so low that they allowed this, but I don’t recall details, and things have probably been tightened up since then.

Comment: @G-Man I don't know if it's possible for a click to be passed back to the browser and cause a shell session to start. FTP is very different since that initiates a session by definition. I'm not saying it's 100% impossible, I don't really know, I just _think_ it's impossible and it's certainly not possible with existing browsers.

Comment: @terdon: I had  started to write a long-winded rebuttal, but it looks like ikrabbe has proven my point — it is possible for a program to do this.

Comment: @G-Man hah! So he did. There I go, flaunting my ignorance again.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do that in general, but in a defined environment, where you can control the client machine B, you can propose that machine B runs a setroot service, you can simply write on your own with nodejs or golang for example and talk to that service when you receive the event. But in any case you don't have any chance (or at least you never should have a chance) if you don't install some extra service on machine B.

Comment: I've never used NodeJs before. You mean i can use a simple javascript like : `run("whatever command on machine B");` ?

Comment: yes, nodejs is very simple to use for such reduced needs.

Answer (score 1):

PHP can change content of textfiles cross the browser for example in /var/www/.../folder/mytextfie.txt
You have only to get the string from that file, whitch can be a command or even command to start a script file.

a cronjob can run to check wether that textfile contains any executable.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo $(cat /var/www/.../folder/commandsperline.txt)
#or 
while read line
    do
    echo "$(${line})"
done< "/var/www/.../folder/commandsperline.txt"
```

context of that textfile:

```
#!/bin bash
#you need to declare absolute path
# chmod 755 /home/user/*.sh -to make executabble all scripts there
/home/user/backup.sh
/home/user/anyscript.sh
```

With te while loop it is possible to execute commands from that text-file.

Comment: but how does that answer the question, regarding a click event in a web page?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.. it is possible with [neutralinojs](https://github.com/neutralinojs/neutralinojs).

You can use `Neutralino.os.runCommand()`. But in your scenario Neutralino cloud mode can be used.